# Google Universal Analytics ecommerce events not registered in Analytics

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-analytics, execution

I am registering some events on a WordPress reservation engine. In this case Google Analytics is loaded via Google Tag Manager, so I have the following situation.

```js
// I have some scripts before that get all the necessary variables correctly so 
// the variables' values are not a problem in this case

// The event is executed on a button click.

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); 
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': id_habitacion,
    'name': nombre_habitacion,
    'category': 'Business & Industrial > Hotel & Hospitality',
    'price': precio_habitacion.toString(),
    'quantity': noches.toString(),
    'currency': 'COP'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

I tried debugging the script and I put a breakpoint on each line.

1. `ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js')` gets executed, no errors. The `ga` objects exists and is analytics.
2. `ga('ecommerce:addItem', {...})` gets executed, no errors.
3. `ga('ecommerce:send')` gets executed, also no errors.

The problem is that I get nothing inside the Analytics panel and after some time also nothing inside the Conversions > E-commerce tab.

I opened the Real-Time section and there I do see my user's other actions like scroll tracking, click tracking and similar, which are created inside of Tag Manager. What I do not receive there are the ecommerce events. After checking, E-Commerce **IS** enabled on the main view of the Analytics property so it's not because of that.

My theory is that perhaps it doesn't have time to initialize and send the info, but in this case it would at least mark an error or something.

Should I move my events to Google Tag Manager instead of having them in my site's scripts?

Everything runs as it should except for the analytics part and it's the only thing I have left to finish to deliver this task to my client.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables you are relying on in GTM you should have everything else dependent on GTM.

I would suggest move it to the GTM in a custom
HTML tag as a datalayer push then use the GTM template transaction tag.

Alternatively it appears you are adding to a cart before actually adding a transaction so it should look like the below and note the price and quantity should be a number not a string.

```
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); 
ga('ecommerce: addTransaction', {
    'id': id_habitacion,
    'name': nombre_habitacion,
    'category': 'Business & Industrial > Hotel & Hospitality',
    'price': precio_habitacion,  // should be number
    'quantity': noches, // should be number
    'currency': 'COP'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

Comment: Isn't the transaction like the equivalent of Purchase? I am registering addToCart in a different spot. Also, I do know that it should be a number but the official docs are kind of confusing on that topic as you can see here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#addTrans

Comment: Yes it is the purchase equivalent that is what the e-commerce report it about. You will find purchases there. Can you clarify what exactly you are expecting to find in the reports?

Comment: The thing is that I don't get anything in the reports, it's supposed to send, but it's not doing anything and I don't get any undefined errors. How much time does it take to process `ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');` ?

Comment: You should allow between 24-48 hours for processing.

Comment: The thing is that it hasn't shown for several days. Also, when I am in real-time the events don't appear when executed. I get events for other things like button clicks and URL changes, but I don't get anything related to eCommerce.

Comment: Can you share the url so I can review? And confirm what you expect to see I.e add to cart event, purchase, etc?